# Nestjs - There is no matching event handler defined in the remote service

Tags: mqtt, nestjs

I'm trying to handle the message published on topic `test_ack` from online MQTT broker using microservices. But I'm getting the error.

`There is no matching event handler defined in the remote service.`

My Code:

**main.ts**

```js
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { Transport } from '@nestjs/common/enums/transport.enum';
var url = 'mqtt://test.mosquitto.org';

async function bootstrap() {
    const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice(AppModule, {
        transport: Transport.MQTT,
        options: {
            url: url
        }
    });
    await app.listenAsync();
}
bootstrap();
```

**app.controller.ts**

```js
import { Controller } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MessagePattern } from '@nestjs/microservices';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
    constructor() {}

    @MessagePattern('test') 
    ackMessageTestData(data:unknown) {
        console.log(data.toString());
        return 'Message Received';
    }
}
```

Comment: What strikes me about your error message. Mine actually gives a similar error message: "There is no matching message handler defined in the remote service." Almost exactly the same, but it says "message handler" instead of "event handler". Wondering if that's the same thing.

Comment: Did you able to solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, I was actually sending the wrong message pattern after all. Our slight difference in error message could be due to the fact that I used Transport.TCP , which may be regarded more as a "message handler" than an "event handler" I guess.

Comment: I'm getting the same error message but it's happening randomly not every time while a call has been produced from origin service to target service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I don't have edit permission, I will post it as a new answer. As mentioned in the above answer. We have to use `@EventPattern('test_ack')`.

The published message should be in format `{data: 'Your message'}` and should be serialized before publishing as mentioned [here](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/2236#issuecomment-497227108).

`client.publish('test_ack', JSON.stringify({data: 'test data'}))`.

Answer (score 0):

You must handle all patterns including undefined type
@MessagePattern(undefined)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I am using nest with microservices.
I am sending commands between microservices like this:

```
client.send(
          { cmd: 'some_command' },
          {
            identity: adminIdentity,
            event: {
              // some payload
            },
          }
        )
```

I am receiving this error `"There is no matching message handler defined in the remote service."` if the command sent with `cmd` has a typo or is in the wrong microservice.

A better practice is to create an enum for commands

// resourcing.commands.ts

```
export enum ResourcingCommand {
  IMPORT = 'import_resourcing',
  EXPORT = 'export_resourcing'
}
```

// resourcing.controller.ts

```
import { Controller } from '@nestjs/common'
import { MessagePattern, Payload } from '@nestjs/microservices'

import { ResourcingCommand } from '@/core/commands/resourcing.commands'
import { ImportResourcingFileEvent } from '@/core/events/import-resourcing-file.event'
import { UserIdentity } from '@/core/interfaces/user-identity.interface'
import { ResourcingService } from '@/services/use-cases/resourcing/resourcing.service'

@Controller('resourcing')
export class ResourcingController {
  constructor(private readonly resourcingService: ResourcingService) {}

  @MessagePattern({ cmd: ResourcingCommand.IMPORT })
  async importResourcingFile(
    @Payload('identity') identity: UserIdentity,
    @Payload('event') event: ImportResourcingFileEvent
  ) {
    return this.resourcingService.importResourcingFile(identity, event)
  }
}
```